# Tkinter how to override my input value to the assigned variable

Tags: python, tkinter

i had created an UI for my code which i can select 2 txt file, input the scoring and the result will  be shown. Be the problem is, the scoring i've input does not override/change and the  result remains the same. May i ask what can I do to override my input data with the current value.

Below are the code for tkinter UI:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.title("Sequence Alignment")

canvas1 = Canvas(root, width = 400, height = 500,  relief = 'raised') #frame
canvas1.pack()

#Title
label1 = Label(root, text='Global Alignment')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 14))
canvas1.create_window(200, 25, window=label1) #location x, y

#Sequence 1
label7 = Label(root, text='Sequence 1:')
label7.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(100, 95, window=label7)

txtarea1 = Text(root, width=40, height=2)
canvas1.create_window(200, 120, window=txtarea1) 

#Sequence 2
label8 = Label(root, text='Sequence 2:')
label8.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(100, 180, window=label8)

txtarea2 = Text(root, width=40, height=2)
canvas1.create_window(200, 205, window=txtarea2) 

#Match Score
label2 = Label(root, text='Match Score:')
label2.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(100, 245, window=label2)

entry1 = Entry (root, width=20) 
canvas1.create_window(210, 245, window=entry1)

#Mismatch Score
label5 = Label(root, text='Mismatch Score:')
label5.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(110, 275, window=label5)

entry2 = Entry (root, width=17) 
canvas1.create_window(220, 275, window=entry2)

#Gap Penalty
label6 = Label(root, text='Gap Penalty:')
label6.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(100, 305, window=label6)

entry3 = Entry (root, width=20) 
canvas1.create_window(210, 305, window=entry3)

#result
label9 = Label(root, text='Best Alignment Sequence:')
label9.config(font=('helvetica', 10))
canvas1.create_window(140, 375, window=label9)


def openFile1():
    tf = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="C:/Users/MainFrame/Desktop/", 
        title="Open Text file", 
        filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
        )
    tf = open(tf)  # or tf = open(tf, 'r')
    data = tf.read()
    txtarea1.insert(END, data)
    tf.close()

def openFile2():
    tf = filedialog.askopenfilename(
        initialdir="C:/Users/MainFrame/Desktop/", 
        title="Open Text file", 
        filetypes=(("Text Files", "*.txt"),)
        )
    tf = open(tf)  # or tf = open(tf, 'r')
    data = tf.read()
    txtarea2.insert(END, data)
    tf.close()

#def score ():
    
#    match_score = entry1.get() #int otherwise it will become string
#    mismatch_score = entry2.get()
#    gap_penalty = entry3.get()
    
    
#    label10 = Label(root, text= 'The Square Root of ' + match_score, font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
#    canvas1.create_window(200, 475, window=label10)
    
#    label11 = Label(root, text= mismatch_score, font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
#    canvas1.create_window(200, 495, window=label11)

#    label12 = Label(root, text= gap_penalty, font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
#    canvas1.create_window(200, 505, window=label12)
    
def result ():
    
    label3 = Label(root, text= aligned_1 + '\n',font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 405, window=label3)
    
    label4 = Label(root, text= aligned_2,font=('helvetica', 10, 'bold'))
    canvas1.create_window(200, 425, window=label4)  
    
button2 = Button(text="Choose Sequence 1", command=openFile1)
canvas1.create_window(200, 70, window=button2)

button3 = Button(text="Choose Sequence 2", command=openFile2)
canvas1.create_window(200, 155, window=button3)
    
button1 = Button(text='Click to align', command=result, bg='brown', fg='white', 
                 font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(200, 345, window=button1)

#button5 = Button(text='Score', command=score, bg='brown', fg='white', 
#                 font=('helvetica', 9, 'bold'))
#canvas1.create_window(200, 455, window=button5)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: UI]

The scoring method i use which i need to perform algorithm

```
match_score = int(input("Enter Match Score: ")) #int otherwise it will become string
mismatch_score = int(input("Enter Mismatch Score: "))
gap_penalty = int(input("Enter Gap Penalty: "))
```

[link to the code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CRSzUdMibKYM1lgG7TgdCv-hxqfIQ6eO/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In short, how to assign the value from the "Entry" which input'ed by user in the UI to the vairable i want to perform the algorithm?

Comment: Is something like `match_score = int(entry1.get())` what you want?

Comment: but how do i apply onto my code? like how can I return the value and code to that line since i run that variable declaration first only then tkinter

Comment: My understanding based on your code, they may be put inside `result()`.  It really depends on your design.

Comment: how can I call a function which allow callback the match_score variable in the tkinter code?

Comment: If you want to access `match_score` in other function, then you need to declare it as global: `global match_score` at the beginning of `result()`.

Comment: Is there anyway i can call back my second line code? i need to rerun the algorithm after i executed my code

Comment: What is *"second line code"*? Actually your posted code is incomplete, better provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: can i just define a function for every line of the code and i call back it through my tkinter code?